# How to use spring aop with class from external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I need to intercept org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#handle method and i use spring aop for that. It is spring class from spring-webmvc.jar. It uses in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet during request proccessing to my rest mvc service.

AOP config:

```
<bean id="contextAspect" class="com.eightbitlab.spring3rest.config.ContextAspect"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="contextAspect">
            <aop:pointcut id="contextPointcut" expression="execution (* org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(..))"/>
            <aop:around method="around" pointcut-ref="contextPointcut"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

Aspect bean:

```
@Aspect
public class ContextAspect {
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("start aspect");
        Object proceeded = joinPoint.proceed();
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("end aspect");
    }
}
```

If I use this aspect with own classes the aspect method is executed. I think that the problem is a class from external jar, but I can't find the solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the signature of [`handle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.html#handle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-) method it is marked as `final`.

As Spring AOP cannot advise `final` methods (*see below excerpts from Spring docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)*) consider intercepting / advising your controller instead.

> You ***cannot*** add advice to ***final*** methods when you use Spring MVC. For example, you cannot add advice to the `AbstractController.setSynchronizeOnSession()` method. Refer to [Section 10.6.1](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies), “Understanding AOP proxies” for more information on AOP proxies and why you cannot add advice to final methods.

**P.S.**: Additionally have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-api-proxying-class) as well for further understanding of AOP proxies.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But "handle" method from interface and I think if I would use dynamic proxy instead of CGI it will be work, but when I add <aop:config proxy-target-class="false"> - no changes(

Comment: In pointcut you have explicitly mentioned to advise the execution of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle` which has the marked it as `final` so irrespective of proxy type it won't work

Comment: Even if the pointcut is updated to `target(org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerAdapter)` the Spring runtime will pick the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` as it is the handler consulted for mapping configured via `@RequestMapping`. Unless you have specific reason to stick with advising `handle` method IMO try advising controller instead.